# Long Polling Implementation

Tags: java, long-polling

I have implement a long poll implementation. What happening is, when the request comes I check whether some data is available and if not sleep the thread and recursively call the method till data is available.

```
int time = 0;
String data;

public void checkme() {    
    time++;
    if (data == null && time < 100) {
        System.out.println("recursive call "+time);
        try {
           Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        checkme();
        } else {
           System.out.println("end recursive call. data available");
        }
}
```

But even when I cancel the request in postman, still the recursive call is happening in background.

So I think my long poll implementation is wrong and which I may need to track the request also from service later or use Queue like data structure.

Comment: That is not what recursion is for. Just use a loop.

Comment: thanks. but still my problem would be there. Any suggestion for a better long poll implementation please?

Comment: @Blorgbeard what is the advantage of loop instead of recursion? and what is wrong with apply recursion in here?

Comment: Loops are the tool designed for repeating blocks of code. You appear to be using recursion as a substitute for `goto` (which exists in C#, by the way, if you really want to use it). Recursion pollutes your stack-trace for no benefit, making debugging harder. And if you "loop" long enough with recursion, your program will crash with a stackoverflowexception. In short, use the right tool for the job: a loop.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening is that when you cancel the request you are doing nothing to break that code or to close the application.

Do you have any way to know if the request is cancelled inside that code? If yes just add that to the condition. Sure the code will be stuck until the Thread awakes but still will do what you want.

EDIT

And you should change from recursion for a simple loop like a while or do...while.

Comment: how can i track the request availability from java class?

Comment: I don't know your code... You need to give more info about how your application works.

Comment: its a spring boot application. the code i place is from my service class method which invoke via a rest controller

Comment: and how can while loop is more efficience than recursion?

Comment: This is not a question about efficiency. Recursion is simply the wrong implemention for what you need. You need a "timed" operation: every few seconds check for something; you use a loop for that kind of tasks...

Answer (score 0):

OK, good old wait/notify.

```
public void waitForData ()
{
  synchronized( this )
  {
    while( data == null )
    {
      wait(5000L);
    }
  }
}

public void provideData ( String dataParam )
{
  synchronized(this)
  {
    data = dataParam;

    // This wakes the waitForData
    notifyAll();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. is this the way long polling implement in backend? by the way, still suppose i have set a time out for 30 minits. Then i make a request and decide to cancel it like in 2 minits, still the backend thread runs for 28 minits rightt?