# implement long poll in vertx

Tags: java, vert.x, long-polling

I want implement a [long poll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) in vert.x.But I do not know how I can implement in vertx. please guide me

Comment: This seems too broad a question.   You can google example long polling implementation questions i.e. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867507/long-polling-implementation  .  For the other part , you need to check out a vert.x tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Make an an http request from the client.

On the server request handler start a periodic timer using `setPeriodic` that will write the data periodically if available via transfer chunked encoding.

Set up a `setTimer` that will eventually `end` the response.